# Diagonalizing $4 \times 4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a $4 \times 4$  matrix with two eigenvalues equal to zero, how can one find the largest eigenvalue?

I know how to find the eigenvalues using the regular way, but this fact should save a lot of work.

Comment: It doesn't: such a matrix could still be non-diagonalizable. You still have to find out about the other two eigenvalues. If for example they are equal but with geometric multiplicity one, then the matrix isn't diagonalizable

Comment: Yes there exist algorithms to do that. But it is difficult to know which to present if we don't know how much or what you have studied.

Comment: @mathreadler What algorithms are you talking about? To help diagonalize a $\;4\times4\;$ matrix knowing **only** that two of its eigenvalues are zero? I doubt there is such a thing...

Comment: the matrix is [8,1,1,0.5;0.25,0.5,0.5,4;4,0.5,0.5,0.25;0.5,1,1,8] , it was a part of  an exam question,  course "advanced statistical mechanics " it have nothing to do with the algebra , I didn't have any idea how to use this fact when solving, we are always interested to know just the largest eigenvalue of a matrix

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Pari-GP says the characteristic polynomial is $x^4-17x^3+\frac{285}{4}x^2$, the largest eigenvalue is $19/2$.

Comment: @DonAntonio it is possible to design algorithms to find diagonalizations (if they exist) which will execute faster the more zero eigenvalues they turn out to have.

Comment: @mathreadler Oh, I know that...I can also do it myself: evaluate  the char. polynomial, find its other two (possibly non zero) values, check the geometric multiplicity of all the eigenvalues and then build the matrix's JCF = Jordan Canonical Form (assuming **all** the roots are in the definition field, of course)...but this is possible **only** after knowing the other two values and some of their characteristics, *not merely knowing* two of its eigenvalues are zero...

Comment: BTW, the matrix **indeed** is diagonalizable according to http://wims.unice.fr/~wims/wims.cgi